# Enable image resizer for all images in the ckeditor

Tags: 9, wysiwyg

I'm using Drupal 9.2.9,

I have some migrated content that comes from an external source. there are some `<img` tags,

the Ckeditor image resizer is working for the images I insert into the editor the upload icon but for the images that come from the content migration, the resizer is not enabled.

[image]

I even tried to add `height` manually to the `<img` tag but nothing appear.

the question is that, how can I enable image resizer for all images within the ckeditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the resizer plugin works if the image has the following attributes:

- data-entity-type="file"
- data-entity-uuid=

So what I did, I create a batch process and go through all the content and find the image, then based on the image I load their `uuid` and file replaced it.

something like the following code may helps people which have similar requirement:

```
if (preg_match_all('~<img.*?src=["\']+(.*?)["\']+~', $node->body->value, $matches)) {
            $URIS = array_unique($matches[1]);
            foreach ($URIS as $imgUri) {
              $imgUriDecoded = urldecode($imgUri);
              $node->body->value = str_replace($imgUri, $imgUriDecoded, $node->body->value);
              $fileData = self::getFileDataByUrl($imgUriDecoded);
              $fileUuid = "xxx-just-for-resize";
              if ($fileData) {
                $fileUuid = $fileData->get('uuid')->value ?? "xxx-just-for-resize";
              }
              // skip Danger.jpg
              if ($fileUuid == "4f6db862-2c5d-4fb1-8d5b-830b89514af4") {
                continue;
              }
              $replacement = sprintf('<img data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="%s"', $fileUuid);
              $node->body->value = str_replace("<img ", $replacement, $node->body->value);
              \Drupal::messenger()->addStatus($node->id());
            }
          }
      $node->setSyncing(TRUE);
      $node->save();
    }
```

The following file helps to get file by fileURI:

```
  static function getFileDataByUrl($fileURI) {
    $file_name = \Drupal::service('file_system')->basename($fileURI);
    $target_file = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('file')
      ->loadByProperties(['filename' => $file_name]);
    $file_data = reset($target_file);
    if ($file_data) {
      return ($file_data);
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
```